# Generate list of neighbor indices for a coordinate in a 3D array

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to generate the indices of some of the neighbors of a given point in a 3D array. The more straightforward way of doing it is by manually writing them. Here's an example were one of the directions will have a range of possible values but the other two could be only 0 or 1. I've used a range from -3 to 3 without 0 in this example to not make it too long, but I use from -6 to 6.

```
def gen_neigh_indices(i, j, k):
    for o, p, q in ((0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3),
                    (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3),
                    (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3),
                    (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3),
                    (0, 0, -1), (0, 1, -2), (0, 1, -3),
                    ...
                    (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0),
                    ...
                    (0, -1, 0), (0, -2, 0), (0, -3, 0),
                    ...
                    (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0),
                    ...
                    (-1, 1, 1), (-2, 1, 1), (-3, 1, 1)):
        yield (i+o, j+p, k+q)
```

I thought of using `itertools` functions but so far I don't know how to change the order of the returned values other than by hand, so I write 3 yields.

```
from itertools import product

def get_neigh_indices(i, j, k):
    for o in range(-3, 4):
        if not o: continue
        for p, q in product(range(2), repeat=2):
            yield (i+p, j+q, k+o)
            yield (i+p, j+o, k+q)
            yield (i+o, j+p, k+q)
```

Is there a way of writing only one `yield`? I don't care about the order of the elements generated, just that it gives all possible combinations.

Comment: You want the same order of this multiple `yield` approach, or the previous hand-coded approach?

Comment: No, as long as in the end it generates all the elements

Comment: Do you consider shift `(3, 3, 3)` as valid shift? Why is it up to 3 in one direction but only 0 and 1 in the other two directions? Can you edit your question to give a description of valid shift?